# Service Model in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, wcf

What is the best model for using services in a silverlight application?
I usually add a wcf service to my ASP.net app and add a service reference to my silverlight application, but anytime I change my service I should update the service reference in silverlight app.
Is there any better and more professional way?

Comment: What do you mean by better and professional?

Answer (score 1):

If you use WCF RIA Service instead of a plain WCF service, it will automatically be updated whenever something on the service end changes.

If you continue to use plain WCF, you will need to update the service anything you change something.

You can also write your own model and expose them to the silverlight client, just like WCF. Everything is almost the same, except ria services was built for this purpose and more.